# ASP.NET load HTML on demang

Tags: asp.net, partial-views

I have ASP.NET 4 application and one edit box for submitting data. There is also Option button which show Dialog(ASP.NET user control embedded into main web page. It is hided by default using JavaScript and Div) with many fields and much html data. To shrink my web page to make it load faster I would like to load that Option dialog(ASP.NET user control) when user click button and not when main page loads. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use AJAX to load the contents of what you are calling the 'Option dialog'. Read up on [UpdatePanels](http://www.asp.net/Ajax/Documentation/Live/overview/UpdatePanelOverview.aspx)